# what is issue in my preg_replace for BB CODE? anyone can help me

Tags: preg-replace, bbcode

Friend! check my code first one is not working but second is working why?
1=>

```
    $value1 = "[b]PHP 2014[/b]";
    $new1 = "/(\[)([bB])(\])/e";
    $v1 = preg_replace($new1,"'<'.'h1'.'>'",$value1);
    echo $v1; 

    /* RESULT::
                PHP 2014[/b]
```

2=>

```
    $value2 = "<b>PHP 2014</b>";
    $new2 = "/(<)([bB])([^>*]>)/e";
    $v2 = preg_replace($new2,"'\\1'.'h1'.'\\3'",$value2);
    echo $v2;

    /* RESULT::
               PHP 2014   */
```

Comment: Don't use the `/e` feature that is obsolete. Take the time to learn regex with a tutorial and to understand what you are doing.

Comment: you mean it had escaped?

Answer (score 0):

Just move the asterisk out of the character class:

```
$new2 = "/(<)([bB])([^>]*>)/";
//               here __^
```

Also remove the `e` modifier because it is obsolete.

Comment: i dont understand im biggner olz tell me with example if you dont mind

Comment: @KashifAsif: you could find a good start at http://www.regular-expressions.info/ .